# EPSON TM-T88IV JavaPos - Disconnected to service

Tags: java, serial-port, usb, javapos

I'm trying to print something to an EPSON TM-T88IV with JavaPos. 
The EPSON is attached with an USB to Serial converter.

This is the code i try:

```
ptr.open("POSPrinter");
ptr.claim(1000);
ptr.setDeviceEnabled(true);
ptr.printNormal(1, "asd");
```

While this is the output in Eclipse:

```
[JposServiceLoader]Custom manager is defined: className= jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager
[XercesRegPopulator]load(): isPopulatorFileDefined=false
[XercesRegPopulator]load: xmlFileName=jpos.xml
[JposServiceLoader]manager.getEntryRegistry().load() OK
[JposServiceLoader]findService: POSPrinter
[SimpleServiceConnection]Disconnected to service OK
```

It immediately says: "Disconnected to service".
I included all ESPON drivers, dll's and libaries correctly, because else there will be another error message.

My `jpos.xml` is generated by EPSON software. I tried both the USB and Serial connection. In my windows managers i configured the USB to Serial converter to COM10, so i tried the COM10 port.

Any information about this subject is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried another piece of code and it gives the same error, but a little more information.

The code:

```
 // instantiate a new jpos.POSPrinter object
 POSPrinter printer = new POSPrinter();

 try
 {
    //open the printer by logical device name
     printer.open("POSPrinter2");         

     //claim exclsive usage of the printer object
     printer.claim(1);

     // enable the device for input and output
     printer.setDeviceEnabled(true);

     // set map mode to metric - all dimensions specified in 1/100mm units
     printer.setMapMode(POSPrinterConst.PTR_MM_METRIC);  // unit = 1/100 mm - i.e. 1 cm = 10 mm = 10 * 100 units

     ...............
```

The log:

```
[JposServiceLoader]Custom manager is defined: className= jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager
[XercesRegPopulator]load(): isPopulatorFileDefined=false
[XercesRegPopulator]load: xmlFileName=jpos.xml
[JposServiceLoader]manager.getEntryRegistry().load() OK
[JposServiceLoader]findService: POSPrinter2
[SimpleServiceConnection]Disconnected to service OK
jpos.JposException: Could not create an instance.
    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_13_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.createCommInstance(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_13_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.open(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(BaseJposControl.java:530)
    at Main.POSPrinterTest.main(POSPrinterTest.java:47)
```

Comment: Dear S.Pols, I have a Vega7000 Series  EFT-POS terminal. Do you have any idea how can I develop program for it? What kind of tools and IDEs and Documents am I need? Where can I find this requirements? And does it have JVM? i.e. does it support Java applications or I must use another programming language? Any light on this issue highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jean. I do not have a lot knowlegde about this subject. Eclipse is the IDE i use to connect to the Epson with the language Java. I used JavaPOS to archieve this with the most of the code of my question. I think you don't need to run your Java (or another kind of application) on your EFT-POS but control it from a connected computer with e.g. JavaPOS. But again my knowlege is limited about connecting POS devices. Take a look at JavaPOS tutorials and manuals for more information about this. For C# i heard something about OPOS, but i never did research about this. Good luck!

Comment: Make sure all the dll files are added too. I had the same issue and adding the some more dll files from java/jre/bin solved the issue

Comment: Sahil: Adding DLLs to java/jre/bin works, thank! Now the question is how to specify custom path when I want to leave DLL somewhere else.